# Spritekit generate never ending map or load long

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Im wondering how to correctly load a very big map, i tried to put 15k pixels height map with original iphone width. But after while loading, it loaded only empty outline drawed by my debbugin function. I don't think that's the correct way, i think im looking for any information or example, how to add new texture when the character is coming up to the end of current texture. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **Building the World** section of [**Explained Adventure**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/BuildingtheWorld/BuildingtheWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140-CH3-SW1) in iOS Developer Library.

Apple explains there how they implemented asynchronous loading of a big map.